# C vs C++ using cl compiler in VS2015

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2015, cl

How does the cl compiler know whether I'm compiling C or C++ code?
Do I need to tell the compiler?
I am running out of the Developer Command Prompt for VS2015.  I originally started this project with c++ code that compiled and ran on a RedHat Linux PC.  I moved it to WIN7 and it would not compile under the cl compiler unless I got rid of the c++ constructs and implemented C equivalents.
A constructor in a header file was one of the issues I had to work around.

Comment: Usually by file extensions. C source files tend to have the ending `.c` while there are a couple of alternatives for C++ (`.cpp` is common).

Comment: I believe both answers could answer this question by now.

Answer (score 5):

As documented [in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55.aspx), it first looks at the filename extension.  If it is .cpp or .cxx then it defaults to C++ compilation.  Almost always good enough to get the job done.  That same page also shows how to force the selection, use /Tc for C and /Tp for C++.  You'd use /TC and /TP to force it for all source files.

Answer (score 4):

The file extensions will give that info.

`.c` files for C and `.cpp` files for C++. Check [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55.aspx) for details.

Also, I found this code [here](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/36775) to show wether a `C` or `C++` compiler was used:

> The code below contains standard, pre-defined macros used at runtime
>   to determine whether a C or C++ compiler was used to compile the code.
>   For C compilers, it also determines the version of the C language
>   standard that the compiler implements). NOTE: Some people prefer to
>   use STDC_HEADERS rather than **STDC**..

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
 printf("C++ compiler\n");
#else
#ifdef __STDC__
#if (defined(__STDC_VERSION__) && (__STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L)) ||/*continue..
    ...on the next line */ (defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__STRICT_ANSI__))
 printf("ANSI X3.159-1999 / ISO 9899:1999 (C99) compiler\n");
#else
 printf("ANSI X3.159-1989 (C89) / ISO/IEC 9899:1990 (C90) C compiler\n");
#endif
#else
 printf("Pre-ANSI (K&R) C compiler\n");
#endif
#endif
```

> The code below determines whether a C or C++ compiler was used to
>   compile the code at runtime:

```
if (sizeof('c') != sizeof(int)) printf("C++ compiler\n");
else if ((unsigned char)1 < -1) printf("Pre-ANSI (K&R) C compiler\n");
else { int i;   i = 1 //* */
 +1;
if (i == 2) printf("ANSI X3.159-1999 / ISO 9899:1999 (C99) compiler\n");
else printf("ANSI X3.159-1989 (C89) / ISO/IEC 9899:1990 (C90) C compiler\n");}
```

---

Just not to rely entirely on a link, here's the info from the docs:

> **Remarks**
>
> By default, CL assumes that files with the .c extension are C source
>   files and files with the .cpp or the .cxx extension are C++ source
>   files. When either the TC or Tc option is specified, any specification
>   of the /Zc:wchar_t (wchar_t Is Native Type) option is ignored. To set
>   this compiler option in the Visual Studio development environment

1. Open the project's **Property Pages** dialog box. For details, see How
   to: [Open Project Property Pages.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e79xc5h1.aspx)
2. Click the **C/C++** folder.
3. Click the **Advanced** property page.
4. Modify the **Compile As** property.

And an example, also taken from the docs.

> The following CL command line specifies that TEST1.c, TEST2.cxx,
>   TEST3.huh, and TEST4.o are compiled as C++ files, and TEST5.z is
>   compiled as a C file.

```
CL TEST1.C TEST2.CXX TEST3.HUH TEST4.O /Tc TEST5.Z /TP
```

Comment: That macro tells me that my C11 compiler is a C99 compiler.

Comment: That's cause that code was written in 2008. So with little modification it can show if it's C11.